# javascript XMLSerializer special characters in attribute

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, escaping

I`ve come across a problem when serializing special characters like TAB, linefeed and carriage return as an attribute value.

According to this http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-xml-c14n-19991109.html#charescaping, these should be encoded as `&\#x9;`, `&\#xA;`, and `&\#xD;` respectively. But calling in chrome:

```
var root = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<root></root>', 'text/xml').documentElement;
root.setAttribute('a', 'first\nsecond');
var serialized = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(root);
```

Gives a string `< root a="first\nsecond"/>` with the linefeed not escaped.

When loading that again:

```
var loaded = new DOMParser().parseFromString(serialized, 'text/xml').documentElement;
loaded.getAttribute('a');
```

returns "first second" and the linefeed was lost to just a space. Has anyone faced this issue before? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Viktor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem, and solved it by writing a function *removeInvalidCharacters(xmlNode)* that removes invalid characters (from nodeValues) in the XML tree. You can use it before serializing to ensure you don't get invalid characters.

[You can find removeInvalidCharacters() in my stackoverflow question on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665288/removing-invalid-characters-from-xml-before-serializing-it-with-xmlserializer)

You can use removeInvalidCharacters() like this:

```
var stringWithSTX = "Bad" + String.fromCharCode(2) + "News";
var xmlNode = $("<myelem/>").attr("badattr", stringWithSTX);

var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var invalidXML = serializer.serializeToString(xmlNode);

// Now cleanse it:
removeInvalidCharacters(xmlNode);
var validXML = serializer.serializeToString(xmlNode);
```

I've also filed an issue report against chrome, but its worth noting that IE9 has its own bugs in this department, so a fix w/o a workaround is probably a long time coming.

Comment: Hey Seth, 
Thanks for the answer.
Looking at your solution it removes the characters. I actually need them. I used a different approach observing the characters are not escaped, but are kept the same:
`var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var invalidXML = serializer.serializeToString(xmlNode);
var xml = escapeXMLCharacters(invalidXML );
`
Luckily I don`t need to deserialize in the end. This solution works for IE9/8 as well. Bear in mind though, that is escapes only linefeeds, linebreaks and tabs, I did not need more...

Comment: Yup! If that's what you need, its a great way to do it. The problem on IE9/8 is that it programmatically entitizes ALL out-of-range characters. Unfortunately, 0x2 and other extended chacters not valid, even in entity form, i.e. &#x2; is not valid. So you if you need to be able to store ANY string handed to you without producing a corrupt XML file (my goal), you have to escape before IE9/8 entitizes.