# Avoid illegal xml characters with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, character-encoding

I had a problem with some illegal xml characters being submitted from a form. I was. Some user had cop pasted a Vertical tab into the form and submitted it. When I copied this out of the database it would show like this(in notepad++)

[image]

I cleaned this with this method

```
function cleanXmlChars(input) {
    var NOT_SAFE_IN_XML_1_0 = /[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\xFF\x85\xA0-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFDCF\uFDE0-\uFFFD]/gm;
    return input.replace(NOT_SAFE_IN_XML_1_0, '');
};
```

Thanks to [Removing invalid characters from XML before serializing it with XMLSerializer()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665288/removing-invalid-characters-from-xml-before-serializing-it-with-xmlserializer)

I thought I was ll done but then I tried holding down `Alt` + 11 and i found out that this character was not removed

♂

Aint this the same illegal character? Wont this cause the same trouble if typed in?

Comment: Why should [♂](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%E2%99%82) be illegal in XML?

Comment: I thought it was the same. http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/vertical-tab-male-symbol-mars-ascii-code-11.html

Comment: Ah, right, that's how good old MS-DOS used to display non-printable characters. Sorry.