# Cleaning bad XML characters in a String in Pentaho

Tags: javascript, xml, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

**The issue**: Receiving bad XML through the web / apps / file exchanges.

I was receiving XML responses through HTTP GET that sometimes would contain bad XML characters in the text.
[image]

That character SUB was showing up in the text and the 'Get data from XML'
 step would fail to read it, stating that ***An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1a) was found in the element content of the document***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665288/removing-invalid-characters-from-xml-before-serializing-it-with-xmlserializer).

I did not need to use the entire JavaScript function contained in the answer, just the part of characters that are not allowed to be used in an XML.

What i did was a simple Replace() function in the 'Modified Java Script Value'

> var str = result.replace(/[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\xFF\x85\xA0-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFDCF\uFDE0-\uFFFD]/gm,'');

This has cleaned the entire XML of bad characters, and made the entire of it readable.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, but do be aware that any technique for repairing ill-formed XML will work on some corrupt instances and fail on others; it's very specific to the type of corruption. It's always best to investigate the root cause and fix the program that's generating the bad XML.

Comment: Well yes, in my case there is no way for me to fix the WebService that's generating the XML because it is from another company, we just consume it, so i had to come up with a fix on my side for it.

Comment: I'm constantly amazed that people are prepared to consume content from a site that delivers ill-formed XML. It's like consuming infected meat. Avoid it like the plague.